# add props to route component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i'm new to react,and i met with a problem that when i use the react-router,and write down the following code:

```
var router = (
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route data = {linksData} path = "/monitor/" component = {App}>
        <Route path = "category/:categoryId" component = {Category}>
        </Route>
    </Route>
</Router>
);
```

ReactDom.render(
    router,ulElement);

i want the component in route can be attached with some props ,like this:

```
<App data={[{id:"01",name:"blah"},{},{}...]} />
```

so that i can iterate the "data" in the app's render function.

and the App component is defined as follows:

```
var App = React.createClass({
getInitialState:function(){
    return {
        city: "全国",
        time: new Date().toJSON().slice(0,10), //2016-04-29
        interval:1000*60 //1 minite
    }
},
render:function(){
    //category:{id: "01",name:"cars"}
    var lis = this.props.route.data.map(function(category,index){
        //pathname+category.categoryId+
        var url_path = "/monitor/category/${category.id}";
        var url_query = {city:this.state.city,time:this.state.time,interval:this.state.interval};

        return (
                <li>
                    <a href={{pathname:url_path,query:url_query}}>{category.name}</a>
                </li>);
    });

    return (
        <div>
            <ul className = "grids">
                {lis}
            </ul>
        </div>)

    }
```

});

can anyone help me with it ? i have tried with the solution of :

```
<Route data = {linksData} path = "/monitor/" component = {App}>
```

but it failed and say this.props is undefined.:(

Answer (score 4):

A function component that does the prop passing is the right way to go.

```
<Route path = "/monitor/" component = {props => <App data={linksData} {...props}/>}>
```

The above passes any custom parameters that you want, like `data` and also passes through all props injected by the router. I like this solution because of its terseness. You could, of course, store the function component in a variable and pass that as a route component, if you'd like your code to be more descriptive.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it's the only one that preserves the router props.

Answer (score 0):

react-router only inject these props
(1) location
(2) params
(3) route
(4) routeParams
(5) children

so if you want to fetch data and apply
1. use onEnter function to get data
2. write high order component

Comment: i wrote the higher component (wrap App like this:   var wrapperApp = React.createElement(App,{data:linksData}); and re-edit the route to :<Route  path = "/monitor/" component = {wrapperApp}>
),but it doesn't work...i don't know where the problems is..can you show me some example?

Answer (score 0):

Use this syntax instead:

```
<Route path="/monitor/" render={() => <App data = {linksData}></App>} />
```